# Is it possible to find out if a file is a zip file?

Tags: java

I have a file without extension. But I need to find out whether that file is a zip file using java. Is there any way to find out that whether that file is in zip format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is: try and open a `ZipFile` on it; if it is not a ZIP, you will get a `ZipException`.

With JDK 7, it is even easier:

```
Files.probeContentType(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))
```

It will return "application/zip" if the file is a zip file!

Bonus: with Java 7, you can access a zip file (or a jar file since a jar is a zip file) as a `FileSystem`, navigate in it, modify files etc. No more of these pesky ZipEntry/JarEntry objects anymore.

Ditch `File`. Fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but currently i am working in JDK 1.6 so that it is not possible for me to check. I tried using ZipInputStream but i am not getting any exception

Comment: Well then try the first solution

Comment: Also i tried the code                                                    File f = new File("/Users/jojo_john/Downloads/123");
   System.out.println("Type:"+new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f)); But the even if 123 is a zip file I am getting the output like Type:application/octet-stream

Comment: Actually the result of calling `probeContentType()` is not always `application/zip`, sometimes it can be `application/x-zip-compressed`.

Comment: Also there's another problem with this solution. I used it on ZIP file with non-obious extension and it return null. (Linux, openjdk-15) So far checking file signature looks best for me. Just like here https://stackoverflow.com/q/33934178

Answer (score 4):

Open it using [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and check whether it throws [ZipException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipException.html)

EDIT: ZipException is the right exception

Comment: I have tried to open a zip file using ZipInputStream but i am not getting an exception

Comment: @JojoJohn - So what do you get?

Comment: InputStream theFile;
  theFile = new FileInputStream("/Users/jojo_john/Downloads/test.pdf");
  ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(theFile);    I have tried the above piece of code and its not getting any ZipException. Please check whether the above sample is wrong